# C# Errors - due to optional parameters or something else?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
    public void RemovalWorker_Start(Applications app = null, Link link = null)
    {
        BackgroundWorker RemovalWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        RemovalWorker.DoWork += RemovalWorker_DoWork;
        RemovalWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += RemovalWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        RemovalWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        RemovalWorker.RunWorkerAsync(arg);
    }
    private void RemovalWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var app = e.Argument.GetType();
        if(app.Name == "Applications")
        {
            Applications RemovalAppliction = (Applications)e.Argument;
            RemovalAppliction.RemoveApplication();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                user.RemoveFromMyApps(user._MyApps[listBox_apps.SelectedIndex]);
            }));
            e.Result = "apps";
        }
        else
        {
            Link RemovalLink = (Link)e.Argument;
            RemovalLink.RemoveLink();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                user.RemoveFromMyLinks(user._MyLinks[listBox_links.SelectedIndex]);
            }));
            e.Result = "links";
        }

    }
```

I am trying to pass an optional parameter to my RemovalWorker. However, I receive the following errors:

```
Inconsistent Accessibility: parameter type 'Applications' is less accessible than method 'MainWindow.RemovalWorker_Start(Applications,Link)'
Inconsistent Accessibility: parameter type 'Link' is less accessible than method 'MainWindow.RemovalWorker_Start(Applications,Link)'
```

Why is this happening? Am I declaring my optional parameters incorrectly? How should I go about fixing this? The "Removal Worker" is instantiated via button click (hitting delete on a listbox item). The argument I would like to pass is whether it is an "Applications" object or a "Link" object.

The function is not 100% complete - I still need to declare what my argument will be, however, I currently can not compile.

Thanks All!

Comment: You have a `public` method that accepts argument types (`Applications` and `Link`) that are internal.

Comment: `Applications` and `Link` are probably not declared `public` (making them `private`), wheras they are used in a function that *is* declared `public`.

Comment: Changing to internal corrected my error - thank you. I am still new and do not know enough about encapsulation. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your Applications and Link is your own class which is not a public class

So when you make public void RemovalWorker_Start the public in this line conflict with nonpublic of Applications and Link